# rotation_euler doing funky stuff on Y and Z

Tags: python, add-on

I have an addon I am creating to find location and rotation of an arrayed object. This is more for exporting the locations and rotation to an external program. I want to have the ability to set the correct orientation after the objects are created. I added a X Y Z rotation button to the addon. I have X working perfect but Y and Z seem to be willy nilly. Not sure how to diagnose why so I can't seem to fix it.

File Link:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/03bw90ucmbbq61h/RlmmTest2.blend/file

Test Steps:

1. Open RlmmTest2.blend
2. Go to the Scripting Tab at the top
3. Press the play button in the scripting panel.
4. Go to the View3d next to the scripting panel or back to the Layout tab.
5. Press “N” to bring up the panel menu.
6. Go to RLMM ToolKit.
7. Make sure Object and Plane are filled in.
   a. If they are not, fill them in with the eyedropper.
8. Press Set Parent/Scale
9. Press Make Instances Real
10. Now press the Set Rotation Buttons.
    a. We are specifically interested in the Y and Z rotation; they seem to be funky.
    b. If you press one button 4 times it will reset it to the original value.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from math import degrees, radians


#WARNING: this is written and tested for blender 2.79
#blender 2.8 and newer will likely have a different python API

class RLMM_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "RLMM_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Objects: Location/Rotation"
    bl_category = "RLMM Toolkit"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = 'objectmode'

#create a panel (class) by deriving from the bpy Panel, this be the UI
    def draw(self, context):
        
        layout = self.layout

        boxLayout1 = layout.row().box()
        # ICON OBJECT_DATA IS THE SQUARE INSIDE THE SELECT BOX
        boxLayout1.label(text="Select Array Objects",icon='EYEDROPPER')   
        boxLayout1.prop_search(context.scene, "prefabOBJ", context.scene, "objects")
        boxLayout1.prop_search(context.scene, "prefabPLANE", context.scene, "objects")
        
        boxLayout2 = layout.row().box()  
        boxLayout2.label(text="Object Instances",icon='LINKED')
        boxLayout2.box().prop(context.scene, "scaleFACES")
        boxLayout2.operator('custom.set_parent', text="Set Parent/Scale")
        boxLayout2.operator('custom.make_instances_real', text="Make Instances Real")
        
        boxLayout3 = layout.box()
        boxLayout3.label(text="Set Rotation",icon='ORIENTATION_LOCAL')
        
        subrow = boxLayout3.row(align=True)
        subrow.operator('custom.set_neg_x', text="-X")
        subrow.operator('custom.set_pos_x', text="+X")
        subrow.operator('custom.set_neg_y', text="-Y")
        subrow.operator('custom.set_pos_y', text="+Y")
        subrow.operator('custom.set_neg_z', text="-Z")
        subrow.operator('custom.set_pos_z', text="+Z")
        
        boxLayout4 = layout.box()
        boxLayout4.label(text="Export Data",icon='EXPORT')
        
        row2 = boxLayout4.row()
        row2.operator('custom.send_to_udk', text="Send to UDK")

class setParent(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_parent"
    bl_label = "Set Parent"
    bl_description = "Parent Object to Plane"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        
        dupeOBJ = bpy.context.scene.prefabOBJ
        dupePLANE = bpy.context.scene.prefabPLANE

        # PARENT OBJECT TO PLANE
        dupeOBJ.parent = dupePLANE
        
        #Does the User want the object to scale? If yes then.
        if bpy.context.scene.scaleFACES == True:
            dupePLANE.use_instance_faces_scale = True
        else:
            dupePLANE.use_instance_faces_scale = False

        # SET INSTANCING TO FACES ON PARENT
        dupePLANE.instance_type = 'FACES'
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class makeInstancesReal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.make_instances_real"
    bl_label = "Seperate And Make Instances Real"
    bl_description = "Seperate And Make Instances Real"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        
        for selectedOBJ in bpy.data.objects:
            selectedOBJ.select_set(False)
        
        dupePLANE = bpy.context.scene.prefabPLANE
        
        prefabCollection = bpy.context.scene.prefabPLANE.users_collection[0]
        
        dupePLANE.select_set(True)

        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = dupePLANE

        bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()
        
        udkCollection = bpy.data.collections.new('UDK Collection')
        
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(udkCollection)
        
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue
            
            prefabCollection.objects.unlink(obj)
            
            udkCollection.objects.link(obj)
            
            obj.name = "PrefabUDK"
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
class setNegX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_neg_x"
    bl_label = "Set Negative X Rotation"
    bl_description = "Change Local Rotation"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            # get rotation eueler
            objRotationNegX = obj.rotation_euler[0] - radians(90)
            
            if objRotationNegX >= radians(360):
                obj.rotation_euler[0] = objRotationNegX - radians(360)
            elif objRotationNegX <= radians(-360):
                obj.rotation_euler[0] = objRotationNegX + radians(360)
            else:
                obj.rotation_euler[0] = objRotationNegX
    
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class setPosX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_pos_x"
    bl_label = "Set Positive X Rotation"
    bl_description = "Change Local Rotation"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            # get rotation eueler
            objRotationPosX = obj.rotation_euler[0] + radians(90)
            
            if objRotationPosX >= radians(360):
                obj.rotation_euler[0] = objRotationPosX - radians(360)
            elif objRotationPosX <= radians(-360):
                obj.rotation_euler[0] = objRotationPosX + radians(360)
            else:
                obj.rotation_euler[0] = objRotationPosX
            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class setNegY(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_neg_y"
    bl_label = "Set Negative Y Rotation"
    bl_description = "Change Local Rotation"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            # get rotation eueler
            objRotationNegY = obj.rotation_euler[1] - radians(90)
            
            if objRotationNegY >= radians(360):
                obj.rotation_euler[1] = objRotationNegY - radians(360)
            elif objRotationNegY <= radians(-360):
                obj.rotation_euler[1] = objRotationNegY + radians(360)
            else:
                obj.rotation_euler[1] = objRotationNegY
    
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class setPosY(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_pos_y"
    bl_label = "Set Positive Y Rotation"
    bl_description = "Change Local Rotation"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            # get rotation eueler
            objRotationPosY = obj.rotation_euler[1] + radians(90)
            
            if objRotationPosY >= radians(360):
                obj.rotation_euler[1] = objRotationPosY - radians(360)
            elif objRotationPosY <= radians(-360):
                obj.rotation_euler[1] = objRotationPosY + radians(360)
            else:
                obj.rotation_euler[1] = objRotationPosY
    
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class setNegZ(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_neg_z"
    bl_label = "Set Negative Y Rotation"
    bl_description = "Change Local Rotation"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            # get rotation eueler
            objRotationNegZ = obj.rotation_euler[2] - radians(90)
            
            if objRotationNegZ >= radians(360):
                obj.rotation_euler[2] = objRotationNegZ - radians(360)
            elif objRotationNegZ <= radians(-360):
                obj.rotation_euler[2] = objRotationNegZ + radians(360)
            else:
                obj.rotation_euler[2] = objRotationNegZ
    
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class setPosZ(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.set_pos_z"
    bl_label = "Set Positive Z Rotation"
    bl_description = "Change Local Rotation"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
        
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            # get rotation eueler
            objRotationPosZ = obj.rotation_euler[2] + radians(90)
            
            if objRotationPosZ >= radians(360):
                obj.rotation_euler[2] = objRotationPosZ - radians(360)
            elif objRotationPosZ <= radians(-360):
                obj.rotation_euler[2] = objRotationPosZ + radians(360)
            else:
                obj.rotation_euler[2] = objRotationPosZ
    
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class sendToUDK(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.send_to_udk"
    bl_label = "Send to UDK"
    bl_description = "Center And Rotate Local"

    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_objects is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue
        
            center = obj.location
            centerX, centerY, centerZ = center[0]*100, center[1]*100, center[2]*100
            d, e, f = round(centerX, 4), round(centerY, 4), round(centerZ, 4),
            
            orientation = obj.rotation_euler
            orientationX, orientationY, orientationZ = map(degrees, (orientation[0], orientation[1], orientation[2]))
            a, b, c = round(orientationX, 4), round(orientationY, 4), round(orientationZ, 4)
            
            textUDK = '{} {}, {}, {} {} {}, {}, {}'.format("Location:", d, e ,f , "Rotation:", a , b, c)
                
            print(textUDK) 
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


#this is the addon info for when you choose to install it
#NOTE: for more information, see addon tutorial in the documentation
bl_info={
        "name":"Ui test addon",
        "category":"tests"
    }

#this function is called on plugin loading(installing), adding class definitions into blender
#to be used, drawed and called
def register():
    #register the classes with the correct function
    bpy.types.Scene.prefabOBJ = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name="Object", type=bpy.types.Object)
    bpy.types.Scene.prefabPLANE = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name="Plane", type=bpy.types.Object)
#    bpy.types.Scene.prefabCURVE = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name="Curve", type=bpy.types.Object)
    bpy.types.Scene.scaleFACES = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Scale Prefab To Plane")
    bpy.utils.register_class(setPosZ)
    bpy.utils.register_class(setNegZ)
    bpy.utils.register_class(setPosY)
    bpy.utils.register_class(setNegY)
    bpy.utils.register_class(setPosX)
    bpy.utils.register_class(setNegX)
    bpy.utils.register_class(sendToUDK)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RLMM_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(setParent)
    bpy.utils.register_class(makeInstancesReal)

#same as register but backwards, deleting references
def unregister():
    #now we can continue to unregister classes normally
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setPosZ)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setNegZ)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setPosY)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setNegY)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setPosX)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setNegX)       
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(sendToUDK)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RLMM_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(setParent)    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(makeInstancesReal) 

#NOTE: during testing if this addon was installed from a file then that current version
#of that file will be copied over to the blender addons directory
#if you want to see what changes occour you HAVE TO REINSTALL from the new file for it to register
    
#a quick line to autorun the script from the text editor when we hit 'run script'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```